# Saving all contents of array through a class into a file.txt and then loading / saving / reading from that same file?

Tags: java, oop, class, save, saving-data

I'm trying to save user input in a file I've referenced known as "contacts.txt". I have to collect user input and store them in a phonebook format and then allow the user to call information that they have saved in this file. I'm having trouble writing input to the "contacts.txt" file. The two functions this is referencing can be seen below are `doSave()` and `doAddEntry()`.

I've been working at this for hours and have hit a brick wall, as well as have ran millions of debugs (probably incorrectly) to see where this is all going wrong...

Could anyone offer any insight that may be able to set me on the right track?

**< Solved >**

Comment: im not that big on java but i think you can use format it as JSON before saving it in the file might make it easy

Comment: If your data is already stored in an object, why don't you store the full object to disk and read it back? Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should Make `Entry` a `Serializable` class and use `Serialization` to save the array of `Entry` `objects` in a file and `deserialization` to get the array of objects back from the stream of bytes saved on file. For Example, consider the code given below . Here `Person` is a class which implements `java.io.Serializable` `marker interface`. Within main body of `SerializeArray`  an array of `Person` is created and it is saved in a file named `Persons.ser` (You can use any name here for the file) using `saveArray`. This array is then read back from the file using `loadArray`.

```
import java.io.*;
class Person implements Serializable //Make Person class Serializable so that its objects can be serialized.
{
    private static final long SerialVersionUID = 20L;
    String name;
    int age;
    public Person(String name,int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Name:"+name+", Age:"+age;
    }
}
public class SerializeArray 
{
    public static void saveArray(Person[] arr)throws Exception //writes the array of Person to a file "Persons.ser"
    {
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Persons.ser"));
        os.writeObject(arr);
        os.close();
    }
    public static Person[] loadArray()throws Exception //Reads the array of Persons back from file.
    {
        ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Persons.ser"));
        Person[] arr = (Person[]) oin.readObject();
        oin.close();
        return arr;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Person[] arr= new Person[3];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = new Person("Person"+i,25+i);
        }
        System.out.println("Saving array to file");
        saveArray(arr);
        System.out.println("Reading array back from file");
        Person[] per = loadArray();
        for (Person p : per)
        {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
To incorporate this concept in your program you should first change your Entry class declaration as something like this:

```
public class Entry implements java.io.Serializable
```

And then change your `doSave()` method as follows:

```
public void doSave() throws Exception {
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("contacts.txt"));
        os.writeObject(entryList);
        os.close();
    }
```

And then change your `doLoad()` method as follows:

```
public void doLoad() throws Exception {
    if (length != 0) {
        //throw new Exception ("I'm not empty"); 
        //File c = new File ("contacts.txt");//No need to access the File here..
        Scanner input = new Scanner(c);
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            Entry e = new Entry();
            e.name = input.next();
            if ("q".equalsIgnorecase(e.name))
            break;
            e.number = input.next();
            e.notes = input.next();
            doAddEntry(e);
        }
        doAddEntry(null);
    }   
}
```

And change your `doAddEntry` method as follows:

```
public void doAddEntry(Entry entry) throws Exception {
    if (entry == null)
    {
      //save file here..
      doSave(); 
    }
    else if (length == 200) {
    //save file here..
    doSave(); 
    throw new Exception("I'm full");
   }
   else
   {
    boolean matched = false;
    for (int i = 0; i<length; i++) {
    if (entryList[i].name.compareToIgnoreCase(entry.name) == 0) {
      matched = true;
      break;
    }
    if(!matched)
    {
      entryList[entryList.length] = entry;
    }
   }
}
```

}

Comment: No clue howd id be able to transmit into my program.

Comment: Any chance you'd know how to work through my doAddEntry? That's where the main error is for me right now.

Comment: also getting this error.

`Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at phonebook.doLoad(phonebook.java:39)
 at phonebook.main(phonebook.java:57)`

Comment: @Tdorno what you want to do in `doAddEntry()`?

Comment: I want to add the entry storing the users name, number, and note in an entryList that will then be saved to the file.

Comment: @Tdorno: ohh sorry my mistake.....I thought that you are using ArrayList ..let me change it..